# Undeleting a "deleted by the author" answer

Tags: discussion, self-deletion

I noticed that there is [an answer deleted by an author here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/1574/759).

It's a brief answer that points to a resource, provides sufficient context, and at least one commenter found useful.

I'd like to undelete it, or repost the resource (perhaps with slightly different contextual support) but ti was deleted by the author. Presumably, it was deleted because some of the suggestions came under challenge. That's only a guess.

I think both the answer and the criticism are appropriate. I think challenging ideas in mathematics is an important part of mathematics education in specific (and STEM education in general). However, I wonder what thoughts or policies there might be about reinstating a deleted answer.

As an alternative, I prepared a new answer with the same resource, but I'd rather reinstate the deleted one because it's gotten 8 votes and the author deserves those votes for providing a decent resource that addresses the question.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. For the specific case: I had an exchange with that user recently and would prefer the post not to be deleted at this  point in time (it might or might not get undelete at a later point). However, you should feel free to post an answer of yours based on it (in fact, based on my conversation I doubt that user would object to it, they might even approve it).  Generally: I think we should be careful with undoing self-deletions, though there can be case were it should be done. I will try to order my own thoughts and write something more detailed later.

Comment: Until recently, that user had only the phrase *please delete me* in his "about me" section. IIRC, this is typically done when one is in the process of contacting SE moderators (not MESE moderators...) to have an account deleted. I see that those words are no longer there; nevertheless, I would be hesitant to undo someone else's deletion (whatever the motivation). [While writing this, I see that @quid has responded as well...]

Comment: Excellent points, thanks. Undelete is such an odd action, which is why I wanted to get perspectives. I myself have deleted an answer of my own (I thought the discussion over it was distracting and nonproductive, and I have to police my productivity fairly closely ATM). So I know people can have important reasons to delete.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - Thanks. FWIW, I added my answer and credited you with pointing out the collected Forsooths. I think there is some value in them, even if they might have been sloppily collected.

Students need opportunities to find they can argue and gain trust in their own mathematical understanding regardless of what some authoritative newsletter decides to print. Everyone makes mistakes.

Comment: @quid, in your first comment above (which starts "Thanks for bringing …"), did you really mean to say that you "would prefer the post not to be deleted at this point in time"?  Or did you mean "not to be undeleted"?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche yes, sorry; I got confused with the double negation I guess.